# Copying large amount of data from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a large amount of data from one workbook to another workbook and am writing the code bit by bit so I get one section working before building the next as this still fairly new to me and I think it easier for me to do this way.

2 questions.... the code below works apart from when I execute the close it closes and saves the wrong work book... I am sorry but I must be missing something basic but i thought putting the WB_From in the statement would tell it which workbook it is??

secondly ... the from file is currently 43,000 rows and could be much larger. I am thinking that if I know the number of rows I could maybe divife by 4 and run 4 smaller copys instead of one - just concerned with the amount of memory thst could be used if I do one copy of the entire range...

hope thats makes sens and I am open to suggestions on alternate ways...

```
    Option Explicit
    Sub OpenMasterSupplierFile()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim WBname As String
    WBname = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, 
    InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1)
    Dim file_path As String
    Dim file_name As String
    Dim WS_FileLoc As Worksheet
    Set WS_FileLoc = Sheets("CONFIG - File Locations")
    file_path = WS_FileLoc.Range("B2").Value
    file_name = file_path & "/" & "Master Supplier Price File.xlsx"
    Workbooks.Open FileName:=file_name
    '
    Dim WB_From As Workbook
    Dim WS_From As Worksheet
    Set WB_From = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=file_name)
    Set WS_From = Sheets("MASTER - Supplier Price File")
    
    Dim WB_To As Workbook
    Dim WS_To As Sheets
    
    
    Set WB_To = Workbooks(WBname)
    Set WS_To = Sheets("MASTER - Supplier File")
    Workbooks.Open FileName:=file_name
    
     
   '===============================================================
    'COPY MASTER SUPPLIER PRICE FILE AND CLOSE WORKBOOK
    
  '===============================================================
    'Get Last row in From File
   Dim FromTbl_LastRow As Long
    With WB_From
        FromTbl_LastRow = WS_From.Range("A" & 
    Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        WS_From.Range("A1:a" & FromTbl_LastRow).Copy
       WB_From.Close SaveChanges:=True
    End With
    
    
    
  '===============================================================
    'CLOSE MASTER SUPPLIER FILE
       
   '===============================================================
   
    ' UNPROTECT SHEET COPYING DATA TO
    
    
    
   '===============================================================
    
    
   '===============================================================
   'CLEAR EXISTING DATA
   '===============================================================
  
   '===============================================================
   'PASTE DATA FROM MASTER FILE TO SHEET COPYING TOO
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: `WB_From` is `ThisWorkbook`, the workbook containing the code. Closing it will halt code execution.

Comment: i did this because when I open the workbook does it not become the active workbook?

Comment: My guess is you want: `Set WB_From = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=file_name)`. Or maybe that should be `Set WB_To = ...`? Either way, if you close `ThisWorkbook`, then code execution stops. If `WB_From` should refer to `ThisWorkbook`, then close it at the very end.

Comment: i will try that ... I was having issue setting the workbook name and could only do it by using thisworkbook..

Comment: `Workbooks.Open` returns a `Workbook` reference that you definitely want to assign to a `Workbook` variable then.

Comment: Try change `Set WB_From=ThisWorkbook` to `Set WB_From=Workbooks.Open(FileName:=file_name)`

Comment: thanks - that has solved the close issue. any thoughts on the breaking up of the copy?

Comment: 40000 isn't breaking the bank in memory,  depending on the amount of columns of course. You can however split them up per column if you'd like or work with `.Value` if there aren't any numbers as text/dates (that's the only issue I've encountered so far with .Value) but that can be remedied with setting the numberformat prior to giving the values over to the other workbook.

Comment: thanks i will test it out ...as it could get to 100,000 + too

Comment: Does Excel blow up if you copy / paste 100k rows manually?

Comment: am going to test it... I am having an issue setting the WB_To workbook... when the SET WS_To = Sheets("MASTER - Supplier File") is reached i get Subscript out of range error... the WB_To  and WB_From Dims seem to both be set to ThisWorkbook...

Comment: I have updated the original code...am getting error when I execute Set WB_To = Workbooks(WBname).... I don't want to hard code the workbook name as if it changed then won't the code fail?

Comment: i manually tested the cut and paste of 43000 rows and was pretty quick... am just stuck in the above comment now...

Comment: Qualify the sheet with workbook ie `Set WS_To = WB_To.Sheets("MASTER - Supplier File")`. If code is in WB_To then use `Set WB_To = Thisworkbook` first. `WB_From` is set when you `Workbooks.Open(FileName:=file_name)`. Also use `Set WS_From = WB_From.Sheets("MASTER - Supplier Price File")`

Comment: @cpd1802. thanks for your help.... am past the setting WB and WS issues now!

Comment: Where do you want `WS_From.Range("A1:a" & FromTbl_LastRow).Copy` to go to on `WS_To` ? Is it just column A to copy ?

Comment: this is all ok now thanks -  I cant see any option to close the question as answered though